# "Exceeded rate limits: exceeded quota for Streaming Table Creation Rate in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

while streaming inserts to bq I got this quota error which i couldn't find anywhere in official documentation.

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "usageLimits",
    "message" : "Exceeded rate limits: Your Project: **** exceeded quota for Streaming Table Creation Rate. For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors",
    "reason" : "rateLimitExceeded"
  } ],
  "message" : "Exceeded rate limits: Your Project: **** exceeded quota for Streaming Table Creation Rate. For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors",
  "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you [follow the UR](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/error-messages)L in your error reason to a list of the error messages you might receive, you'll see that you've been rate limited.

See the rate limits for query jobs [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#query_jobs) and rate limits for API requests [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#api_requests).

### Update

Google doesn't appear to differentiate by streaming or not, but they do cite [table quotas](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#standard_tables) at 1500 DML operations per table per day (not what you were doing, but still useful to note) and a max of 5 DDL operations every 10 seconds (and creating tables would fall under this bucket).

Limit your new table creations to 5 every 10 seconds or so and you shouldn't run afoul of the quotas.

Comment: there is no mention of streaming Table Creation Rate on any of quotas.I just want to know the threshold and its rate is in sec/min or hour?

Comment: @ANSHUMANDWIVEDI Updated the answer to reflect table-specific quotas